# What is a JSON octet and why are two required?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, variables

I have incoming data, which I store in a variable `messages`:

```
connection = ContextIO::Connection.new(key, secret)
messages = connection.all_messages(:account => account, :limit => 100, :since => (Time.now - 3000.day ))
```

The variable `messages` is formatted in JSON.  Then I execute this:

```
 foo = JSON.parse(messages)['data']
```

Most of the time this works.  Every now and again, I get this error message:

```
  A JSON text must at least contain two octets!
```

That error message then refers to the line `JSON.parse(messages)['data']`

1. What is an octet?
2. Why must JSON text contain at least two octets?
3. How do I prevent my code from breaking every time `messages` does not have two octets?

Thanks!

Answer (score 50, accepted):

1. An octet is a group of 8 bits. Today, octet is synonymous with byte, but byte historically referred to any "native" grouping of bits, and that could mean 4,6,7, or 8 bits.
2. JSON text must contain at least two octets because the top-level structure of a JSON document is an array or object, and the shortest representations of those are `[]` and `{}`, respectively.
3. Check the value `messages`. It is probably empty, unset or consists of a single digit (like `4`), which is *not* valid JSON, but accepted by many JSON implementations.

Answer (score 6):

While I totally agree with the other answer, in my case I had a valid `JSON` string but was still receiving the "JSON text must contain at least two octets" error message when trying to `JSON.parse`.

My issue was that I was not specifying content type of `application/json`. Once I added that, `JSON.parse` worked without error.

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Stephen, this is exactly what I need! Where did you add the line "application/json"?