# Apply monkey patch for JSON parsing in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, patch

I'm trying to handle edge-case issues with the BigCommerce API returning invalid JSON objects, resulting in un-paired octects as discussed here: [A JSON text must at least contain two octets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8390256/a-json-text-must-at-least-contain-two-octets)

I believe the solution is to deploy the code (from that thread):

```
module JSON
  def self.parse_nil(json)
    JSON.parse(json) if json && json.length >= 2
  end
end

parsed = JSON.parse_nil(json)
```

Where do I deploy this code to apply the patch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Patches like these are typically added in an otherwise empty `.rb` file in the `/config/initializers` directory (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420680/monkey-patching-in-rails-3) for an example).  Note that the patch should not include the last line:

```
parsed = JSON.parse_nil(json)
```

That was added for demonstrative purposes.

Comment: I've put it in `/config/initializers/json.rb` and it seems to be loading, however it's still throwing the unparsable JSON response error.  Am I missing a line to override the `parse` method?

Comment: The idea of this patch is to use `JSON.parse_nil` wherever you would have used `JSON.parse`.  If this call is being made by some other library, you'll need to make an alias method chain to have this resolve properly.

Comment: Gotcha.  Went in and modified the BigCommerce gem to invoke `parse_nil` instead of parse and all is good. Thanks :)

Comment: Be aware that modifying a gem will work for that installation, but will need to be reenacted for new deployments (including every current and future development, test, staging, and production environment).  The recommended approach would be to either alias_method_chain in the same initializer, or to monkey patch the gem implementation as well via another initializer.