# JSON::ParserError: A JSON text must at least contain two octets! (for non-nil input)

Tags: ruby, json, post, sinatra

So, I realize [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8390256/a-json-text-must-at-least-contain-two-octets) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7200554/what-is-json-octet-and-why-are-two-required) have already been asked on this subject, but (unfortunately) my case appears to be different.

The [Sinatra README](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html) says to do the following for POST data:

```
post "/api" do
  request.body.rewind  # in case someone already read it
  data = JSON.parse request.body.read
  "Hello #{data['name']}!"
end
```

When I try this, I get:

```
JSON::ParserError: A JSON text must at least contain two octets!
```

The other questions deal with a case in which the data is nil, or poorly formatted (`\"` instead of `"`), but mine appears to be good. If I open irb and JSON.parse the exact same string that I'm POSTing, it works just fine.

This is the command I'm using for testing:

```
curl -XPOST http://localhost:5000/endpoint --data '{"foo":"bar","blah":"wat","abcdefghijklmnop":"qrstuvwxyz"}'
```

I feel like this should be insanely obvious, because parsing POST data is a really basic thing for a webserver to do. Apparently not though.

**Edit:** If I call `logger.info Hash[params]`, I get:

```
{"{\"foo\":\"bar\",\"blah\":\"wat\",\"abcdefghijklmnop\":\"qrstuvwxyz\"}"=>nil,   "splat"=>[], "captures"=>["endpoint"], "resource"=>"endpoint"}
```

...but I'm not sure if/how that helps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try something along these lines:

```
post "/api" do
  request.body.rewind  # in case someone already read it
  data = JSON.parse (request.body.read || '{"name":"Not Given"}')
  "Hello #{data['name']}!"
end
```

Comment: So this worked. But then I changed it basically back to the original and that worked too. So I have no idea what was going wrong. My theory is that initially I was sending bad data (I was using a different curl request) but then in trying to get the bad data to work, I messed up the ruby code. Then when I had a good curl request, the ruby code wasn't parsing correctly. But gave the same error as before. Good lord. Anyway, your answer led me back to sanity, so thanks.