# Sensu cli stash json error

Tags: json, sensu, uchiwa

I am trying to create a sensu stash using the cli as such:

sensu cli stash create silence/client

This then gives me a json file to create the stash, I put in my requirements as such:

```
{
  "path": "silence/client",
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  "content": {
    "reason": "reason here",
    "source": "uchiwa",
    "timestamp": 1493220469
  }
}
```

But when i save the file i get this error:

> JSON::ParserError: A JSON text must at least contain two octets!

I am not too familiar with json, what does this mean?

Comment: I just ran this without issues. Which versions of Sensu and sensu-cli are you using? I tested running `Sensu` version `0.12.3` and `sensu-cli` version `0.6.3.2`. The command:
`$ sensu-cli stash create "silence/testing"`
This prompts for a JSON input, for which I added:
`{
  "path": "silence/jstest",
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  "content": {
    "reason": "testing",
    "source": "uchiwa",
    "timestamp": 1494331612
  }
}`
And this worked without issue.

Answer (score 0):

As per [this question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7200582/6871089), your json file may have been empty or malformed somehow.

Currently, if you create an empty or malformed json file for a stash, you get the following output from sensu-cli:

```
sensu-cli stash create 'silence/test'
The stash you created has invalid JSON.
```